# How to hide a push notification after some time?

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I have to hide a push notification after 1 minute. What should I do in my service worker to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Notification.close() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close). You can get the [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification) object with [ServiceWorkerRegistration.getNotifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications).

For example:

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('Title', {
      body: 'Body.',
    })
    .then(() => self.registration.getNotifications())
    .then(notifications => {
      setTimeout(() => notifications.forEach(notification => notification.close()), 60000);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: The  notificationEvent variable in promise is undefined and thats why it is not closing . Please Help!!

Comment: Try the alternative solution.

Comment: From Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) second solution is working weird. Whenever I push messages from my server, I am getting default show notification (This site has been updated in the background).

Comment: According to spec [showNotification](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-serviceworkerregistration-shownotification), the first example won't work because the promise will resolve to undefined.

Comment: About second example, when you use `getNotifications` on Chrome(windows, Version 73.0.3683.103 official build 64-bit) after using `showNotification`, and after sending several notifications, only the last one will trigger `self.onnotificationclick`

Comment: I removed your first solution because it did not follow either the current spec or current browser implementations as `getNotifications()` returns "A Promise that resolves to `undefined`." (From what I could tell, this has been in the spec a very long time, but I do not know what MDN and browser implementations were like 5 years ago.) It's a big change, but one I think makes sense. If you disagree, feel free to roll it back, though.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [Notification.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close).

Also, to get the notifications, you have to use [ServiceWorkerRegistration.getNotifications()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications). To identify a specific notification, you can use Notification.tag.

Finally, you must keep a Promise alive inside "waitUntil" to prevent the service-worker to shut down before your timeout triggers:

```
event.waitUntil(
  self.registration.showNotification('Title', {body: 'Body.', tag: 'my-unique-tag'})
    .then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000)) // keep service worker alive
    .then(() => self.registration.getNotifications())
    .then(notifications => {
      const notification = notifications.find(notification => notification.tag === 'my-unique-tag')
      if (notification) {
        notification.close()
      }
    })
  );
```