# JavaScript Notifications API, FCM how to close notification after a delay from service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When page is in the foreground I can display and close notification using this code:

```
var n = new Notification("Hello");
setTimeout(function() {
    n.close();
}, 2000);
```

When page is in the background (service worker) I can display notification using this code:

```
var messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload)
{
    return self.registration.showNotification('Hello');
});
```

How to close notification after a delay from service worker?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a push notification after some time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549931/how-to-hide-a-push-notification-after-some-time)